# No matching function for call to 'ANDingOctets'

Tags: c++, function, syntax-error, call

I'm getting the error "no matching function for call to 'ANDingOctets' for some reason, **wanna help my understand why?** The function looks okay to me... (It's not a complete function though yet.)

```
//
//  ANDingOctets.cpp
//  Egetskojs
//
//  Created by Axel Kennedal on 2014-02-12.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Axel Kennedal. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string ANDingOctets(string octetIP, string & octetSubNet);

int main(){

    /* EXAMPLE ADDRESSES
    string IPaddress = "192.168.0.12";
    string subNetMask = "255.255.255.0";*/

    string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110","11111000");
    cout << netID << endl;

    return 0;
}

string ANDingOctets(string octetIP, string & octetSubNet){
    int subNetBits;


    for (char index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
        if (octetSubNet.at(index) == '1') {
            subNetBits++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    cout << subNetBits << endl;
    return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is a reference:

```
string ANDingOctets(string octetIP, string & octetSubNet);
                                           ^
```

and you can't pass a temporary string by non-constant reference - that's a slightly quirky language rule intended to prevent you accidentally modifying the wrong thing.

If the function is not intended to modify the argument, then pass by value (like the first argument) or constant reference (`const string &`).

If it is intended to modify it (which doesn't seem to be the case), then you'll need to pass a non-temporary variable:

```
string subnet = "11111000";
string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110",subnet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string literal in this case where needs a string pass by reference. You can change

```
string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110", "11111000");
```

to

```
string tmp = "11111000";
string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110", tmp);
```

In addition, `int subNetBits;` is used without initialization, you'd better change it to:

```
int subNetBits = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
string myString("11111000");
string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110", myString);
```

In your solution, you have a constant string, ie not a reference to a string, which cannot work.

Something that would probably be better would be to pass both parameters as *const reference*:

```
string ANDingOctets(const string &octetIP, const string &octetSubNet);

// usage:
string netID = ANDingOctets("10110110","11111000");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ANDingOctets()` function takes a string *reference* as its 2nd parameter. You can't pass a literal string value as a non-const `std::string` reference.

When I compile this with gcc, I get this warning:

> ```
> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> test.cpp:21: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a temporary of type ‘const char*’
> test.cpp:13: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘std::string ANDingOctets(std::string, std::string&)’
> ```

Comment: What do you mean with "literal string"? So what am I supposed to do to fix it? Thanks for helping out :)!

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor The token `"11111000"` is a string literal (not a `std::string`). Since the function expects the latter, and `std::string` has a constructor which takes a `const char *`, the compiler is implicitly constructing a temporary `std::string` object using your literal as an argument. However, the temporary object cannot be passed as a non-const reference. The compiler assumes the function might modify the argument, which wouldn't make sense since it's a temporary object that goes out of scope when the call is complete. If you made it a `const` reference it would work.